# Wildcards and generics error

Tags: java

The code below is throwaway, a failed idea to get an Enumeration to work in the new foreach loop, however I'd like to get it compiling since I keep running into an issue with generics and wild cards.  For whatever reason I cannot see how to fix it.

So, what changes need to be made to make this compile?

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;


public class Main
{
    private ZipFile zipFile;

    public Set<String> entries()
    {
        final Set<String>                             names;
        final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>         enumeration;
        final IterableEnumeration<? extends ZipEntry> iteratable;

        names = new HashSet<String>();

        // zipFile.entries() returns "Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>"
        enumeration = zipFile.entries();

        // this line won't compile
        iteratable  = new IterableEnumeration<? extends ZipEntry>(enumeration);

        for(final ZipEntry entry : iteratable)
        {
            if(!(entry.isDirectory()))
            {
                names.add(entry.getName());
            }
        }

        return (names);
    }
}

class IterableEnumeration<T>
    implements Iterable<T>
{
    private final Enumeration<T> enumeration;

    public IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<T> e)
    {
        enumeration = e;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        final EnumerationIterator<T> iterator;

        // yeah cannot do this since an Iterable is supposed to work multiple times on the same object and Enumeration is descructive...
        iterator = new EnumerationIterator<T>(enumeration);

        return (iterator);
    }
}

class EnumerationIterator<T>
    implements Iterator<T>
{
    private final Enumeration<T> enumeration;

    public EnumerationIterator(final Enumeration<T> e)
    {
        enumeration = e;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (enumeration.hasMoreElements());
    }

    public T next()
    {
        return (enumeration.nextElement());
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannt remove via an Enumeration");
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Main.java:26: unexpected type
found   : ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry
required: class or interface without bounds
        iteratable  = new IterableEnumeration<? extends ZipEntry>(enumeration);
                                             ^
1 error
```

Comment: and the question is....?

Comment: what do changes have to be made to make it compile... sorry thought that was clear... I'll update it.

Comment: well yeah I guess I could have put the error message in... oops & thanks

Comment: This might help: [http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what what the programming language you use before java?

Comment: I have used Java since May of 1995 I think (JDK 1.0 alpha 2)... before that C++, C, Smalltalk, Pascal, Basic, x86 assembler (in no particular order).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot specify a wildcard when constructing a parameterized type. This is the correct syntax:

```
iteratable  = new IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry>(enumeration);
```

As you noted, there's difficulty in implementing `Iterable` with an `Enumeration` because `Enumeration` is one-time use, while code can rely on `Iterable` to create as many fresh `Iterator` objects as it wishes. You could safely use this in enhanced for-loops, but it would be unsafe to pass such an `Iterable` to any other method.

---

Oscar is right, the above change is not sufficient. I overlooked the fact that the underlying `enumeration` is "`? extends ZipEntry`". In addition, make the following changes:

```
class IterableEnumeration<T>
  implements Iterable<T>
{

  private final Enumeration<? extends T> enumeration;

  public IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<? extends T> e)
  {
    enumeration = e;
  }

  ...
```

and

```
class EnumerationIterator<T>
  implements Iterator<T>
{

  private final Enumeration<? extends T> enumeration;

  public EnumerationIterator(final Enumeration<? extends T> e)
  {
    enumeration = e;
  }

  ...
```

These changes basically mean, *"`IterableEnumeration<T>` can collaborate with an `Enumeration` of any sub-type of `T`."*

Comment: I tried removing the ? in that code but doesn't work. What's the reason? The new message is: Cannot findconstructor IterableEnumeration(java.util.Enumeration<capture#125 of ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>)

Comment: I don't get it. Why is not possible to create such constructor?

Comment: <? extends T> never thought of that one.  Thanks.  I had a brutal generic a couple of weeks ago - I wound up making it stretch over about 10 lines... I'll have to revisit it now.