# How do I fix this Java generics wildcard error?

Tags: java, generics, foreach, bounded-wildcard

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620934/wildcards-and-generics-error), TofuBeer was having problems creating a genericized `IterableEnumeration`.

The answer came from jcrossley3 pointing to this link http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html which pretty much solved the problem.

There is still one thing I don't get.  The real problem, as effectively pointed out by erickson, was that:

> *You cannot specify a wildcard when constructing a parameterized type*

But removing the wildcard in the declaration didn't work either:

```
final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable 
                  = new IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry>(zipFile.entries());
```

Results in the following error:

```
Main.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor IterableEnumeration(java.util.Enumeration<capture#469 of ? extends java.util.zip.ZipEntry>)
location: class IterableEnumeration<java.util.zip.ZipEntry>
        final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable = new IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry>(  zipFile.entries());
                                                         ^
1 error
```

But the samples in the JavaSpecialist do work:

```
  IterableEnumeration<String> ie =
              new IterableEnumeration<String>(sv.elements());
```

The only difference I can spot is that in the JavaSpecialists blog, the `Enumeration` comes from a `Vector` whose signature is:

```
public Enumeration<E> elements()
```

while the one that fails comes from `ZipFile` whose signature is:

```
public Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries()
```

Finally, all of this is absorbed by the for-each construct and the static make method suggested in the link

```
for(final ZipEntry entry : IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() ))  {
    if(!(entry.isDirectory())) {
        names.add(entry.getName());
    }
}
```

But!! the point in that newsletter was not to solve this problem, but to avoid the need to specify a generic type, just because the syntax looks ugly!!

So.. my questions is:

## What is happening?

Why doesn't creating an instance of `IterableEnumeration` work when the parameter is an `Enumeration` whose type is `<? extends SomeClass>` ?  And why does the make for-each construct swallow the problem?!!!

Why does this work:

```
for(final ZipEntry entry : IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() ))  {
```

but this not work?

```
final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable
                     = IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() );
```

Below is a (slightly) modified version of TofuBeer's original code:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    private ZipFile zipFile;

    public Set<String> entries() {

        final Vector<ZipEntry>    vector = new Vector<ZipEntry>();
        // why this works.
        //final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable = new IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry>( vector.elements() );

        // but this do not.
        //final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable = new IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry>( zipFile.entries() );

        // nor this 
        final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable = IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() );

        // And what's with the for-each that doesn't care about the type?    
        final Set<String>   names = new HashSet<String>();

        for(final ZipEntry entry : IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() ))  {
            if(!(entry.isDirectory())) {
                names.add(entry.getName());
            }
        }

        return (names);
    }
}

class IterableEnumeration<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private final Enumeration<T> enumeration;

    public IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<T> e) {
        enumeration = e;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() { 
             public boolean hasNext() {
                return (enumeration.hasMoreElements());
            }

            public T next() {
                return (enumeration.nextElement());
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove via an Enumeration");
            }
        };
    }
    // As suggested by http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html
    // but doesn't help with: final IterableEnumeration<ZipEntry> iteratable = IterableEnumeration.make( zipFile.entries() );
    public static <T> Iterable<T> make(Enumeration<T> en) {
        return new IterableEnumeration<T>(en);
    }
}
```

I want to understand it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening with the foreach loop, but you need to add the wildcard to your declaration of IterableEnumeration to accept the unspecified type returned from ZipFile.entries().

Replace

```
    private final Enumeration<T> enumeration;

    public IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<T> e) {
        enumeration = e;
    }

    public static <T> Iterable<T> make(Enumeration<T> en) {
        return new IterableEnumeration<T>(en);
    }
```

With

```
    private final Enumeration<? extends T> enumeration;

    public IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<? extends T> e) {
        enumeration = e;
    }

    public static <T> Iterable<T> make(Enumeration<? extends T> en) {
        return new IterableEnumeration<T>(en);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I also modified the make() method.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem here is that when [ZipFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) was changed to support generics, the maintainer chose to make the return type of the `entries()` methods `Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>` (presumably so that the method in the subclass  `JarFile` can return `Enumeration<JarEntry>`). This causes the problem you are seeing.

Because `Enumeration<T>` is used covariantly (as it is always - it only ever returns values), you should always make method arguments take `Enumeration<? extends T>`.